# inline-block element with no text renders differently

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="background-color:red">
  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;height:20px;width:20px;"></div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow">
  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;height:20px;width:20px;">hi</div>
</div>
```

When rendered in FF or Chrome the height of the red div is 26px, whereas the height of the yellow div is 20px. How can I make the red div render the same as the yellow div, but without it containing any text?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*just a thought:*

as long as there's no text in the div, it's treated like a inline-image (or something else), and so it's vertical-align is set to 'baseline'(or text-bottom or whatever) instead of 'bottom'.

*the solution:*

to correct that, set `vertical-align: bottom;` on your inner divs. there's absolutely no need to put a space or invisible element into it, like others mentioned (but that would be an (ugly) solution, too)

Comment: My pleasure! if this was the answer you're looking for, it would be nice to accept it by klicking the tick-mark on the left (you should always accept an answer it answered your question)

Comment: Yeeha!! I hate CSS for problems like this, but I love SO for people like you

Comment: nasty little bug, doesn't even show up under computed properties in the inspector

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a zero-width space (`&#8203;`) in the "empty" node?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a specific height, use

```
min-height: 1em;
```

Using a space of some sort is a different height in some circumstances.

Comment: min-height worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's lame, but you could add a `&nbsp;` to the empty div.

`inline-block` is a funny display type and without content because other properties like `font-size` and `line-height` can actually growing the element taller than 20px.