# Why this trick centers text vertically in dynamic height div (and why it breaks)?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940314) very interesting. It works to vertically center text of any length in a div of any height. Basically it uses a empty `<span>` tag directly in front of the node containing text, and

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span></span><p>This is really really long text but it will be centered vertically.</p>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div { 
    background: yellow; 
    color: red;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center; /* horizontally center */
    height: 300px; /* any height */
    padding: 0 20px
}

div span:first-child {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; 
}

div p {
    margin: 0;        
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Also even more interesting is if you separate closing span tag (`</span>`) and opening paragraph tag (`<p>`) on two separate lines, or if you add a whitespace between the two, the trick breaks.

My question is - how does this trick work? How is span helping center the text? And why does it break when a newline/whitespace is added in HTML between closing `</span>` tag and opening `<p>` tag?

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate both points: https://jsfiddle.net/axRxE/385/

Comment: there were two answers to this questions? why did they get deleted???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is - how does this trick work? How is span helping center the text?

Since you give the span [`inline-block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block) property, the span then **inherits** it's parent height (with `height: 100%`) - which in you example is a **fixed 300px**. And since you gave also the same property to the *paragraph*, those two elements are one next to each other. See an example:

```css
#parent {
  height: 300px;
}
span {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;

  /* some width and background-color for demonstration */
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span></span>
  <p>foobar</p>
</div>
```

And you also put `vertical-align: middle` (which works with `inline-block`) on both of them, which gives them that align (you only need to add that property to the *larger one*):

```css
#parent {
  height: 300px;
}
span {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;

  /* some width and background-color for demonstration */
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;

  /* added vertical-align */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span></span>
  <p>foobar</p>
</div>
```

---

> And why does it break when a newline/whitespace is added in HTML between closing `</span>` tag and opening `<p>` tag?

That's simple - when you use `inline-block` there is always [a whitespace issue between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements). And since you didn't add some width to the *paragraph*, it takes all the `width` it can take, and with that additional width from the whitespace, the *paragraph* goes **below** the `span`.

In your example, your parent has 120px `width`, the *span* uses 0px, so the *paragraph* takes all of the parents width, which is 120px. Now, with the additional whitespace (which is ~ 4px), since she *paragraph* uses all the width, the whitespace doesn't fit so the paragraph "breaks" - it goes below the span.

---

Also check:

- [inline-block element with no text renders differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053575/inline-block-element-with-no-text-renders-differently)
- [Vertical-Align: All You Need To
  Know](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/).

Comment: nice explanation. +1 for the links.