# Div element moves when changing the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a keypad type input screen but when my code changes the innerHTML of the element where the number is displayed, the element shifts down a bit. Why is it doing that?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<head>
<style>
body{
 width:480px;
 height:800px;
}
.keypad {
 background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
    border: 2px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
.keypad1{border-radius: 50%;}

.floating-box_input{
 background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 90px;
 border: 6px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
 margin: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 96px;
 line-height: 90px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="1"></div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="2"></div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="3"></div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="4"></div>

    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('1')">1</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('2')">2</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('3')">3</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('4')">4</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('5')">5</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('6')">6</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('7')">7</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('8')">8</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('9')">9</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('0')" style="margin-left:144px;">0</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="deleteNum()">
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:40px; color:white;">backspace</i>
 </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function inputDigit(numIn) {
      var curr = 1;

      while (document.getElementById(curr).innerHTML != "") {
        curr++;
        if (curr == 12) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (curr == 12) {
        return;
      } else {
        document.getElementById(curr).innerHTML = numIn;
      }
    }

    function deleteNum() {
      var i;
      for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (document.getElementById(i).innerHTML == "") {
          continue;
        } else {
          document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = "";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My code isn't finished and there are some things that need to be changed, I just took what was needed to figure out why the number display is shifting down.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align the text to the top or bottom to make sure the divs won't move when the text is added.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<head>
<style>
body{
 width:480px;
 height:800px;
}
.keypad {
 background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
    border: 2px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
.keypad1{border-radius: 50%;}

.floating-box_input{
 background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 90px;
 border: 6px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
 margin: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 96px;
 line-height: 90px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="1"></div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="2"></div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="3"></div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="4"></div>

    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('1')">1</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('2')">2</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('3')">3</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('4')">4</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('5')">5</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('6')">6</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('7')">7</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('8')">8</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('9')">9</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('0')" style="margin-left:144px;">0</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="deleteNum()">
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:40px; color:white;">backspace</i>
 </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function inputDigit(numIn) {
      var curr = 1;

      while (document.getElementById(curr).innerHTML != "") {
        curr++;
        if (curr == 12) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (curr == 12) {
        return;
      } else {
        document.getElementById(curr).innerHTML = numIn;
      }
    }

    function deleteNum() {
      var i;
      for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (document.getElementById(i).innerHTML == "") {
          continue;
        } else {
          document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = "";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `floating-box_input` elements are empty. This is know for `inline-block` elements. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053575/inline-block-element-with-no-text-renders-differently).

If you were to add empty content to your elements, you will notice that they don't change when you click the numbers. Empty `inline-block` elements are aligned differently.

I modified your script so you can see what I'm talking about. A proper solution would be to use `vertical-align`, or even better, `flexbox`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<head>
<style>
body{
 width:480px;
 height:800px;
}
.keypad {
 background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
    border: 2px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
.keypad1{border-radius: 50%;}

.floating-box_input{
 background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 90px;
 border: 6px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
 margin: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 96px;
 line-height: 90px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="floating-box_input" id="4">&nbsp;</div>

    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('1')">1</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('2')">2</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('3')">3</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('4')">4</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('5')">5</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('6')">6</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('7')">7</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('8')">8</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('9')">9</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="inputDigit('0')" style="margin-left:144px;">0</button>
    <button class="keypad keypad1" onclick="deleteNum()">
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:40px; color:white;">backspace</i>
 </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function inputDigit(numIn) {
      var curr = 1;

      while (document.getElementById(curr).innerHTML != "&nbsp;") {
        curr++;
        if (curr == 12) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (curr == 12) {
        return;
      } else {
        document.getElementById(curr).innerHTML = numIn;
      }
    }

    function deleteNum() {
      var i;
      for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (document.getElementById(i).innerHTML == "") {
          continue;
        } else {
          document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = "";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```